# Apache rewrite url rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, apache2

In my `apache2.conf` file, I have given the code but I want to rewrite the url. i.e when I go through the url, it should remove the port number 8080 & should redirect to  http://myapp.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
       ServerName example.com  
       DocumentRoot /home/myapp  
      <Directory /home/myapp/public>
        AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
         RewriteEngine on
         RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp.example\.com$ [NC]
          RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.example.com:8080/$1 [R=301]
          Allow from all   
      </directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this might help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this

```
  <VirtualHost *:80> 
           ServerName example.com  
           DocumentRoot /home/myapp  
          <Directory /home/myapp/public>
            AllowOverride all
             Options -MultiViews
             RewriteEngine on
             RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp.example\.com:8080$ [NC]
              RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.example.com/$1 [R=301]
              Allow from all   
          </directory>
        </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: No its not working with this code its giving error [ Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at myapp.example.com Port 80 ]

Comment: How about this , replacing ^myapp.example\.com:8080 with ^(myapp.example.com):8080$

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this question just by changing this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapp\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.example.com:8080/$1 [R=301]
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Good. It will be helpful.